# Why put the business logic from controller to the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For rails development, I was told that it is better to move logic from controller to model, anyone could point me the reason about this?

Comment: [Check this link](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model`)

Answer (score 2):

It depends. In the spirit of object oriented programming it is better for a model (class) to encapsulate it's own data and behaviour that is related to manipulating that data. The way the data is manipulated is of course dependant on your business logic but if it's tightly coupled with the data then it should belong in the model.

That doesn't mean all business logic belongs in the models, the controllers should be responsible for marshalling interaction between the user and the data and possibly any interactions between models.